# Why does window.location.href return about:blank in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I'm trying create a simple bookmarklet to capture the title and url of a page. Here's basically what I have:

```
<a href="javascript:location.href='http://supergroovsite.net?url='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(window.document.title)">bookmarklet</a>
```

It works fine in other browsers but Chrome returns 'about:blank'. Sometimes it returns the correct url. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you in solving your problem:
[location.href is about:blank in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=93199). Hope it helps